# How to change domain name in Glassfish generated urls?

Tags: glassfish-3

my Glassfish instance uses my Windows computer name as domain name in urls, as so :

```
http://mymachine-567125f:8080/TemplateEJBService/TemplateEJB
```

Obviously, `mymachine-567125f` is not known of any DNS, and as a consequence, url directly leads to the deepest void of intergalactic space.

So, is there a way to tell glassfish to instead use `localhost`, or even my ip address, for its generated urls ?

Comment: can you please explain how you made it work? i can't make it work i still need to use :8080 else it won't load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt Handy's answer did not work for me. However, the solution that Matt gave in his comment to his answer did the trick. I'm repeating it here to give it more weight. There are two ways to do this:

1. Set the `server name` for the HTTP listener in GlassFish admin console:
   Configurations > server-config > Network Config > Network Configuration > Network listeners > http-listener-1 > Tab "HTTP" > "Server name".
2. Edit *domain.xml*, more specifically the `server-name` attribute in

   <network-config>
        <protocols>
            <protocol name="http-listener-1">
                 <http server-name="">

Answer (score 4):

You can change the host name with the Glassfish admin console:

Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> *Your server's name* (usually: "server")

If you click on the virtual server, a page opens, containing an input field "Hosts". By default this should contain `${com.sun.aas.hostName}`.

Change it to your host's name.

Be careful if you have other webapps on your server. If you only want to change the hostname for a particular application and not for all, you have to create a new virtual server and assign the host nameto it.

Alternatively you could get the same by editing *domain.xml* in your domain/config dir. But I think you will be faster with the (often bashed and often slow) admin console.

Comment: Strangely, when i change this setting, nothing changes in my web-app

Comment: Well, I once more looked into my (working) configuration and found another place, where I changed the hostname: at the http-listener configuration (Network Configuration --> Network listeners --> http-listener-1 --> Tab "HTTP" --> "Server name").

Comment: None of this has any effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

To Change the Default Host Name Using the **asadmin** Command

> asadmin set
>   server-config.jms-service.jms-host.default_JMS_host.host="0.0.0.0"

or you can set hostname

> asadmin set
>   server-config.jms-service.jms-host.default_JMS_host.host="hostname"

You can get more information from this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjsdi/index.html

Comment: Didn't help neither... Running Glassfish-4.1