# Deploy GlassFish using Netbeans generate java.net.MalformedURLException: Bad URL path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, netbeans-7, hostname

I'm using Netbeans to develop a web application. When I try to deploy the web application GlassFish generate the following error.

```
WARNING: JMX007: Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: 
{ name = system, Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 0.0.0.0, Port = 8686, 
AcceptAll = false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = false} 
having exception java.net.MalformedURLException: Bad URL path:
 _abc.def.int:8686/jndi/rmi://XYZ_abc.def.int:8686/jmxrmi
SEVERE: java.net.MalformedURLException: Bad URL path: 
_abc.cde.int:8686/jndi/rmi://XYZ_abc.cde.int:8686/jmxrmi
```

Please notice my full computer name is **XYZ_abc.cde.int** and I can't change the host name.
According to [this](https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/bug-unable-start-freshly-installed-glassfish-netbeanside-cannot-start-jmx-connector) it's illegal to have an underscore for host name. But unfortunately I can't change the host name.

Is there a way to deploy GlassFish using Netbeans without changing the computer name? I searched to find a method to change the host name for GlassFish, but no luck.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply go to 
path of the server source `\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml`

then under the tag

```
<admin-service system-jmx-connector-name="system" type="das-and-server">
```

change `address="0.0.0.0"` to `address="127.0.0.1"`

and then under the tag

```
<admin-service system-jmx-connector-name="system">
```

change `address="0.0.0.0"` to `address="127.0.0.1"`

hope to solve with you it worked for me...

Comment: Not working. Now the error is Warning:   Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system, Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 127.0.0.1, Port = 8686, AcceptAll = false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = true} due to exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:
[How to change domain name in Glassfish generated urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510889/how-to-change-domain-name-in-glassfish-generated-urls)

Are you developing and deploying on localhost? If yes, try localhost instead to set up the server connection...

Answer (score 0):

In GlassFish admin web console open **Configurations -> server-config -> Admin Service** and set **Address** parameter to **localhost** or your IP.

Comment: I have same problem but view admin console wants username and password. I don't have any.