# Where to change base-url for glassfish war deployment?

Tags: deployment, glassfish, war, base-url

Im following a glassfish tutorial for uni where i export a webapp and it tells me to deploy it. I deploy it and it provides links to launch it, but the server (by default for some reasons) launches it at: `computername.ispname:8181/webapp` instead of the expected `localhost:4848/webapp`where if i go to, i get a 404.
Where/how can i change the base URL?
[image]

Following any of these links or `localhost:4848/T4`  or `localhost:8080/T4` doesnt load the webapp eg. `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

Comment: tried changing default-config - virtual server
`${com.sun.aas.hostName}` to `localhost` and same for server-confier- virtual server. didnt help. tho i will try restarting server.

Comment: restart didnt fix it. the tutorial didnt use domains, but if i try starting the server with just `./startserv` it tells me 
`"The domains directory /Applications/glassfish4/glassfish/domains
contains multiple domains.  Please specify a domain.
Available domains: domain1, tute4
Command start-domain failed."` and so i need to start with a domain `.startserv domain1` and deploy into the domain. im wondering if that has changed my base-url?

Comment: changed default and server configs - virtual servers "Hosts" to `127.0.0.1` and it still didnt fix it!

Comment: i tried all solutions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510889/how-to-change-domain-name-in-glassfish-generated-urls
And still hasnt fixed it. I used the install the of GF the tutorial linked me to:
`http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip`
And now Ive been suggested to use homebrew's install of glassfish, so hopefully that will give me less headache.

Comment: still happening after using homebrew GF

Answer (score 0):

Im putting this one down to some Eclipse madness.
I setup a webEEapp and Glassfish server in IntelliJ, using the exact same Homebrew version of Glassfish from above, and this madness was gone! 
Jut had to [fix autodeploy by updating iJ JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365498/problems-with-glassfish-4-debug-in-idea-12-1) and then i was fine.